# Django query returns objects but .count() reports 0

Tags: python, sql, django

I have somewhat complex query that required .extra() function:

```
contractors = models.Contractor.objects\
        .filter(is_authorized=True, user__is_active=True,
                categories=cat,
                globalcontractorrank__isnull=False)\
        .exclude(user__name='')\
        .extra(
                select={'fullrank':
                    'COALESCE(ranking_subcategorycontractorrank.points, 0) + '
                    'ranking_globalcontractorrank.points'},
                tables=['ranking_subcategorycontractorrank'],
                where=['ranking_subcategorycontractorrank.category_id IS NULL OR '
                    'ranking_subcategorycontractorrank.category_id = %d' % cat.pk])\
        .order_by('-fullrank', '-subcategorycontractorrank__points', '-user__registered_on')
```

This yields quite unexpected results:

```
In [19]: contractors.count()
Out[19]: 0

In [20]: len(contractors)
Out[20]: 900

In [21]: contractors.count()
Out[21]: 900
```

It seems that the django compiler simplifies the SQL for COUNT() query in a way that gives different results. However, once the query has been run in the original form, the result is cached and subsequent COUNT() queries return the right number of matches.

Is such behavior right or I should file a bug?

Comment: Given the relative complexity of this code, its specificity to Django, and the fact that it *might* be a bug, I think you should be browsing/posting over at [Django Code](https://code.djangoproject.com/query). A quick-and-dirty search on 'count()' turned up things like [Inconsistent results of QuerySet count() method using PostgreSQL backend prior and post the QuerySet evaluation](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26434) and other interesting things.

Comment: If possible, you should rewrite your query so that it doesn't use `extra()`. The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#extra) warn that `extra()` is an old API they aim to deprecate. It sounds like you may have found a bug in `extra()`, but it is unlikely that it will be fixed.

Comment: Even if you file a bug report it would be ignored because there will not be any new development in extra(). It's possible to write a COALESCE function call using the ORM. Post your model and explain what you want to achieve and we can have a crack at it.

Comment: you post a question but don't respond to any of the comments. Not very polite is it?